# Conditional Excel Formula including "Or"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I properly include an `OR` function in a conditional Excel formula?

I have two formulas that I would like to combine with an `OR` function as follows:

```
=IF(AI6="Left Urn Selected", BB6)

=IF(AI6="Right Urn Selected", BC6)
```

..so that if the first condition is true, the value in `BB6` will be shown. And if the second condition is true, the value of or `BC6` will be shown.

In context...

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Thanks for any advice you can provide.

Comment: no problem, I made my comment an answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a nested IF like this:

```
IF(AI6="Left Urn Selected", BB6, IF(AI6="Right Urn Selected", BC6, ""))
```